# How to make form data a part of the application state? (Alternative approach to managing state in an Ember Application?)

Tags: ember.js, ember-router

I am currently looking for a feasible approach to store form data globally in my Ember Application. The state of the form must get reflected in the URL. I have not yet seen an Ember example managing this kind of state, since routes always revolved around certain entities/models that get displayed by an Application.

Soo.. what is my Usecase?

> When the user enters my app, he may modify some settings of my app in a form (e.g. location and time). I would like to have this information as part of the application state. **Why? The state of the settings could be shared by the user with others users easily, as he could share the current URL of the application.**

This is my current idea for an implementation:

- I could store the current settings in a global location, e.g. in my router.
- This enables me to access the stored settings in the methods serialize and deserialize of my main route (and potential other routes).

What's your opinion on my current idea for a solution approach? Is there maybe a appropriate Ember feature i have missed?

Comment: Do you also need the functionality of the router (i.e. updating URL as the users moves through different UI states of the app)? If not, you could use a plain `Ember.StateManager` instead of the router, and manipulate the URL by via hash or pushState yourself.

Comment: Yes the URL should be updated automatically when moving through the app. I am currently trying this approach. I am storing the state of the form in my router. When a part of the form updates, i am updating this central reference and pass it as context to my routes. This is working quite well so far.